# Get-stream: Activity propagation via 2 follow relations?

Tags: feed, getstream-io

**Situation:**

- Imagine two models: Songs and Playlists
- You can add reactions (verbs, e.g. "like", "dislike", etc.) only to Songs.
- Each Song lists its aggregated verbs, e.g. 2 users liked the Song, 4 disliked it.
- I set up two feed groups: Song_flat (flat) and Song_aggregated (aggregated)
- Verbs are added to Song_flat while Song_aggregated follows Song_flat.
- So far that works fine incl. realtime updates.

**Challenge:**

- Playlists should display an aggregated view (again by verb) across all the Songs in this Playlist.
- I set up two feed groups: Playlist_flat (flat) and Playlist_aggregated (aggregated)
- Playlist_flat follows all of the Song_flat feeds associated to it. Playlist_aggregated follows Playlist_flat.
- So in total: Playlist_aggregated follows Playlist_flat follows lots of Song_flat feeds.
- I need the intermediate Playlist_flat feed in order to consume real time updates of all the Song_flat changes which the Playlist_aggregated feed cannot provide.
- **Issue**: While Playlist_flat lists the verbs added to its songs immediately, **Playlist_aggregated does not contain any verbs** despite Playlist_aggregated following Playlist_flat.

**Questions:**

- Is it an error in getstream or are verbs not propagated via 2 link followerships?
- So, must I require Playlist_aggregated to follow directly the Song_flat feeds and NOT via Playlist_flat?

Thank you.
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

Feed updates are propagated to followers only to direct followers; 2nd or higher degree follower feeds (eg. follower of a follower) are not supported. My suggestion is to let an aggregate playlist follow each song (or add activities to the song feed and target the playlist with the `to` targeting field)

Comment: Understood. As I need to react on updates to the aggregated date, I need the flat feed anyway: Activity removals cannot be reflected in an already aggregated feed as only the getstream id is included in the socket message. For that I needed the the foreign_id. So I let the Playlist flat feed follow the songs and aggregate right in the frontend. Do not know what happens when the number of activities increase massively, though. Is there a limit on the number of activities per feed? For Songs, no problem. As Playlists can have lots of Songs this could get into the 1000s...